# draw html in java not javascript

Tags: java, html, jsp, dom, web

let say I have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app/minfoManagementdetail.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String detailMinfoManagementPost(@ModelAttribute("searchPageNavigationVO") SearchAppVO searchAppVO, 
            HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {

        List<EgovMap> attachList =  (List<EgovMap>) amtAppMonitAtchFileService.selectAppMonitAtchFiles( searchAppVO.getFindMonitSn());


}
```

I want to draw this attach List at minfo.jsp

```
<div class="attachFileList" id="attachFileList" style="display: none;"></div>
```

actually I want to perform this

```
for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(resultDetail.amtBrdTblAtch).length; i++) {
    html += "<a href='/file/download.do?type=brd&sn="+resultDetail.amtBrdTblAtch[i].atchFileSn+"'>"+resultDetail.amtBrdTblAtch[i].orgFileNm+"</a><br/>";
                                }
$("#attachFileList").html(html);
```

action in java not in javascript.
is it even possible?

Comment: just want to know any javascript people know how to do it

Comment: so you want to set the inner html of an element on server side using java?

Comment: yes i want to access the html with java

Answer (score 0):

I really prefer to send object data and render it in the .jsp files, as that is what the JSTL exists for. Unless you're doing this asynchronously. In that case you may want to consider using a template framework (like [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org) for Spring or [VueJS](https://vuejs.org) for js) and render a portion of the DOM as a fragment, or just use js to append your result.

Hope this be useful